# What does the notation $\leftarrow$ mean in $\mathbb{P}(F(X)\leq u) = \mathbb{P}(F^\leftarrow)(F(X))\leq F^\leftarrow (u))\;$?

Tags: probability-theory, notation

I looked up the question in other topics, but I am not 100% certain I understand the explanation / it applies to my case. So, I am going to ask just in case.

While reading these lecture notes:
https://github.com/qrmtutorial/qrm/blob/master/slides/qrm_07.pdf

I stumbled upon the following notation (see proof of Lemma 7.2):

$$\mathbb{P}(F(X)\leq u) = \mathbb{P}(F^\leftarrow)(F(X))\leq F^\leftarrow (u))$$

My question is: Is the $\leftarrow$ sign equal to "$-1$" , i.e. for the inverse of $F(X)$), or do I misunderstand the equation completely?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Some authors use $F^{\leftarrow}(A)$ for the preimage of $A$ under $F$. This is the only time I have myself seen that notation used.

Comment: If I want to use the proof for another proof, can I simply write $F^-1(u)$ ?

Comment: You can use whatever notation you want so long as the meanings are the same.

Comment: Well, the meaning here is the same, so I am going to use it. Thank you guys !

Comment: Here $F^{\leftarrow}(A)$ is not the pre-image of $F$ under $A$, i. e. the set $\{\text{$x$ for which there exists a $y\in A$ such that $y = F(x)$}\}$, but the generalized inverse, i. e. $\inf\{ y : F(x)\geq y\}$

Comment: Could you clarify the difference ?